# program checking string of characters for capital letters

Tags: javascript

Ok, i have a function which checks if a letter is upper case and returns 'true' or 'false' value.

```
function isUpperCase(aCharacter) {
    return (aCharacter >= 'A') && (aCharacter <= 'Z');
}
```

now I would like it to check a string of characters e.g. 'AdfdfZklfksPaabcWsgdf' and after the program encounters capital letter it will execute function decryptWord on all small letters after this letter and until next capital letter and so on. Function decryptWord works fine on single words i just cant get it work on more than one ;(

```
function decryptMessage(cipherText, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet) {
    for (var count = 0, count < cipherText.length; count++) {
        if (isUpperCase(cipherText.charAt(count))) {
            decryptWord(cipherText, indexCharacter, plainAlphabet, cipherAlphabet)
        } else {
            //i dont know what to do next
        }
    }
}
```

can you tell me if i'm going in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not certain if this is actually relevant to your problem, but you've a syntax error in your code. Change that `,` in your `for` loop's parentheses to a `;`.

Comment: the code you've shown would call `decryptWord()` with the _full_ cipherText every time an uppercase character is detected. I guess for Alberti's Disks (right?) this needs to be decrypted word by word.

Answer (score 10):

Have you considered a regex that splits before each uppercase character?  For instance

```
"AdfdfZklfksPaabcWsgdf".split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

Results in:

```
["Adfdf", "Zklfks", "Paabc", "Wsgdf"]
```

This way, you can manage one "word" at a time; the first character of each is always upper-case, the rest are lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

Your `isUpperCase` function returns `false` for a space character, so the code treats space characters and lowercase characters the same. That's probably why it's barfing on multiple words but not single ones.

Instead of dealing with upper- and lower-case letters, why not [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the input on [non-word characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters)? Something like this:

```
var words = cipherText.split(/\W/), // \W means non-word characters
    numWords = words.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
    decryptWord(words[i]);
}
```

Comment: As an input i will have one string of characters e.g. "AcdgsFsgRsi" every capital letter indicates start of a new word. It is also a signal character for decryption and is used in function decryptWord. All i have to do to execute function decryptWord on every block of letters separately e.g. "Acdgs" "Fsg" "Rsi"

Comment: Okay, then you'd just split as [@Andy recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090182/program-checking-string-of-characters-for-capital-letters/6090350#6090350).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using two variables in the `decryptMessage` function. The first variable, `last_caps`, will store the index of the previous capitalized letter. The second variable is `count`, which will work very similarly to how it does already. This allows you to know where the previous capital letter was, so when you find the next capital letter, you can use `decryptWord` on the lowercase letters between them.

**An iteration of the for loop**

- If the character at index `count` is uppercase, then:

  - If `count - last_caps > 1`, then:

    - Use `decryptWord` to decrypt the substring starting at `last_caps` and ending at `count`. Manipulate the values as necessary to include/exclude the capital letters.
  - Overwrite `last_caps` with `count`. (`last_caps = count`)
- End of `for` iteration.

Answer (score 0):

columns is array of string and leave fully cases such as  upper or lower case

```
function cipherText(columns) {
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        if (!isAnyCase(columns[i])) {
            columns[i] = columns[i].split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
        }
    }
    return columns;
}

function isAnyCase(text) {
    return (text == text.toUpperCase() || text == text.toLowerCase());
}
```

calling of function

```
var columns = cipherText(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function to split on Capital Letters:

```
String.prototype.splitForCapitalLetters = function () {
    var string = this;
    if (string.length) {
        string = string.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
    }
    return string;
};
```

Call:

```
"AnyString".splitForCapitalLetters();
```

Result:

```
["Any", "String"]
```